# Simple way to decrement number within a repeating range

Tags: c#, mathematics

I currently have a solution to increment numbers within a range:

```
i % x + 1
```

*Where `x` is the maximum number in the range and `i` is the previous number.*

It is nice and simple, and gives this array: `1,2,3,4,1,2...`

I also need to do this in reverse, which should produce this array: `1,4,3,2,1,4,3...`

This is my solution:

```
i == 1 ? x : (i - 1 % x)
```

Is there a way to do it without the ternary operator?

Comment: could you give some more of the code that you use?  I want to recreate and see if I can do it, I have an idea but I want to test it first

Comment: `1,4,3,2,1,4,1`? Shouldn't it be `1,4,3,2,1,4,3`?

Comment: If you do this so often that you want to shorten it, maybe it's time for a couple of helper methods?

Comment: @svick its in a helper method - I was sure there was a pure math solution but I couldn't work it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some thoughts:

```
(i + x) % x == i //For i >= 0 && i < x
```

Then

```
(i + x - 1) % x
```

Gives us the range from 0 to x-1.
We want the range from 1 to x so we change this to:

```
(i + x - 2) % x + 1;
```

But I don't think it's particularly readable, so your ternary code might end up being better.

Comment: Ternary is also a lot faster judging by this simple JSPerf (I'm doing it in both C# and JS) - http://jsperf.com/modulus-vs-ternary

Comment: @Jamie: If your concern is performance, you could substract from i (and from the conditional) when it's initialized (and use decrement instead of precrement).  However, even on my machine the slower version is performing over 7 million operations per second.  I doubt this is going to be your bottleneck.

Comment: Very true! My main concern is not performance for something as simple as this - but seeing as ternary has both greater readability and speed it seems sensible to opt for that!